# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on Jhipster

Tags: java, spring, maven, jhipster

I send restTemplate.exchange() from spring-boot project:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String URI = "http://localhost:8888/getResource";
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        ResponseEntity<List<PayScreenMenu>> screenMenus = restTemplate.exchange(URI, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PayScreenMenu>>() {});
```

to jhipster method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getResource", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody List<PayScreenMenu> getResource() {
    ....
    return payScreenMenuList;
}
```

after the return jhipster method returned error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.getType()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;
```

on pom.xml jhipster project added version jackson converter:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you run mvn dependency:tree and post the resolved dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

The Resource class that the JHipster method is in might be annotated with something like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
```

If that's the case, you need to change `String URI = "http://localhost:8888/getResource";` to `String URI = "http://localhost:8888/api/getResource";`.